# Invisible element on page which I can't locate

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, responsive-design

Has anyone ever tried to convert a site to mobile, and come across a gap in the page which they can't seem to either find or remove?

Usually this is either a clear or a float problem, but in this case I can't find at all. It only seems to appear on mobiles. Might anyone be able to help? Thanks in advance :)

http://dev.ioncamera.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the basket and language elements? If so its probably because the width of all of the elements across the header are larger than the window width. Try amending the width of the elements with media queries when the screen size falls below a certain width...

```
 @media(max-width: 350px){
  selector{    
   attribute:rule
  }   
 }
```

Comment: Hi Julian,

Thanks for the answer - much appreciated :)

Yep, I'm using media queries - for mobile's it's below:

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 550px) {}

Doesn't seem to make any difference. If you view the page on mobile, you can swipe across to the right with a gap there. I'm trying to make it so the banner fills the page, but with the gap being there it zooms the page out to accommodate the slider and the gap.

Comment: is it an overflow-x issue?

Comment: if so, you could try forcing the width of the body to equal the window width with jquery (element.css("width", xx+'px')), and add overflow-x: hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Julian - thanks for your answer. The problem was with viewport. This wasn't in the script:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Once I put that in, the screen displayed as intentional on mobiles and iPads. Beginner stuff, but sometimes you forget the basics :)